# Wappalyzer addon not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, add-on

suddenly my wappalyzer stop working on firefox. i dont know why? removed and install it again but same case. also install the previous version bt no progress sign here. can anyone tell me whats the problem about that?

n.b: using firefox 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Chrome, and was updated this morning to version 2.33. According to some of the reviews of the extension other people are having the same problem as well. Check to see if Firefox's version was updated this morning, that could be the problem.

Version: 2.33
Updated: August 14, 2014

Comment: my chrome addon was also updated and not working.may be its has some bug